# Different ways of populating a list from an array

Tags: java

What is the difference between these two styles of initialization :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

and

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

One thing that I can make out is that in the latter case, we are not using the `ArrayList` class. But then, which class's object (list) are we creating here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first creates a mutable `List`, the second is of fixed size. `ArrayList` is not the only implementation of `List`. `Arrays.asList` returns its own implementation which is of fixed size, i.e. individual elements can be updated but elements cannot be added or removed.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference I see is this second will create a immutable `List` object.

Answer (score 1):

In `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);`

`Arrays.asList(arr)` return a fixed-size list backed by the `arr` array of String type. It doesn’t implement the add or remove method (as it says in the specs is fixed size list).

So if you are trying to add something like these

```
list.add("StackOverflow")
```

You will be getting an **UnsupportedOperationException (Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported.)** because the returned list is of fix size.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html

In `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));`

`new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr))` returns a list containing the elements of the fixed-size list backed by the `arr` array of String type, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

So here if you are trying to add something like these

```
list.add("StackOverflow")
```

**Then it will be getting added that's the difference.**

Answer (score 0):

for the first one you pass the list *arr* into the static method *asList* which return a List, you then make a new ArrayList with the result of the method as a constructor argument.

for the second one you use the result of the static method as the object directly.

Comment: you are explaining the constructor which he can read fro the official sites. he is asking for the difference.